# Can I just detect line breaks at the beginning and at the end of a file? This function verifies all line breaks within the file?

Tags: php, file, newline

i use this function to detect new Lines in a file; but it return true with all new line detect include all inside the files; but i need filter only at start and at the end.

```php
// $file is the path plus name of the file location localy.
private function CheckFileIntegrity($file) {
    $dl    = false;
    $fileR = file($file);
    foreach ($fileR as $line) {
        if (!strlen(trim($line))) {
            $dl = true;
        }
    }
    return $dl;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to verify about the file? That it contains line breaks? That it contains at least one blank line, or no blank lines?

Comment: if containt empty lines (line breaks) at start or at end, last line need to have string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to solve the problem i need to inverse the array of line, and add else statement with break:

```
private function CheckFileIntegrity($file) {
        $dl        = [];
        $dl['st']  = false;
        $dl['smg'] = '';
        $fileR     = file($file);
        $c         = 0;
        foreach ($fileR as $line) {
            $c++;
            if (!strlen(trim($line))) {
                $dl['smg'] .= 'Incorrect space found the file: <b>' . $file . '</b> Line: <b>' . $c . '</b>';
                $dl['st'] = true;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        if ($dl == false) {
            $fileR = array_reverse($fileR);
            foreach ($fileR as $line) {
                if (!strlen(trim($line))) {
                    $dl['smg'] .= 'Incorrect space found the file: <b>' . $file . '</b> Line: <b>' . $c . '</b>';
                    $dl['st'] = true;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return $dl;
    }
```